# Some 301 redirect challenge - Quotation mark to the homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Someone wrote a post and embed a link to my website. The issue is that they put a broken url: `http://MyWebsiteDomain.com/"`  - so this Quotation mark in the end make this link broken.

I have tried to email the writer but with no success, so I want to redirect this broken address to my homepage.

My website is with WordPress and I'm using some redirect tool. I tried 
from `/"` to  `http://MyWebsiteDomain.com/` but it is not working.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Just a guess .. maybe you need to escape the quote ? ( /\"

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\"$ /$1
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\"$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Add the rule right under your RewriteBase, also you don't need 2 RewriteEngine on lines

Comment: Hi Jon Lin,

Where do I need to add those solutions you gave me?
here is mt .htaccess content:

`# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: To be more specific, just add `RewriteRule ^(.*)\"$ /$1 [L,R=301]` right under `RewriteBase /`

Comment: I have tried both options, `RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)\"$ /$1` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)\"$ /$1 [L,R=301]` under the line `RewriteBase /` line, and it is still not working ):

Comment: Ok so the solution I did was to redirect from `/%E2%80%9C` to my website

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to redirect from `/%E2%80%9C` to my website